# Im trying to write a bot that automaticly downloads images and then sends them into a diffrent channel, but im running into an Error

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

The full error Code is

Ignoring exception in `on_message`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\...\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\...\DiscordBot\cogs\Post_image.py", line 33, in on_message
await self.bot.send(self.bot.get_channel("images")
file=discord.File(f"images/{picture}"))
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I tried moving the channel variable around but that didnt help and i didnt find any solution online.

For completion my code in rewrite

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.bot.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    image_types = ["png", "jpeg", "gif", "jpg"]
    # channel = self.bot.get_channel("images")
    for attachment in message.attachments:
        if any(attachment.filename.lower().endswith(image) for image in image_types):
            await attachment.save(f"./images/{attachment.filename}")
    for picture in os.listdir("images"):
        if picture.endswith(".png") or picture.endswith(".jpeg") or picture.endswith(".jpg"):
            await self.bot.send(self.bot.get_channel("images"), file=discord.File(f"images/{picture}"))
        os.remove(f"images/{picture}")
```

Comment: Okay, so. You see how the error message quotes one of your lines of code, starting with `await self.bot.send(self.bot.get_channel("images")`? Do you see how it says that the `'Bot' object has no attribute 'send'`? Did you *understand* that part? Does it make sense to you? Were you *expecting* to be able to use `.send` here? Why? What does the documentation say? What do you want the line of code to do? You want to send a message to a *channel*, right? Do you have code to get that channel? If you have the channel, do you know how to send to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.bot` and `send` do not go together. What I would do is make a variable that defines the channel that you want the images to be sent to then make the bot send it. Something like this..

```py
channel = self.bot.get_channel(imagechannelidhere)

await channel.send(file=discord.File(f"images/{picture}"))
```

`channel` will make the bot find the channel that you want the images to be sent to.
So we make the bot send the file to the channel by doing `await channel.send`

What I mean by `imagechannelidhere` is the channel ID of the channel you want the images to be sent to by your bot. You must put the ID, not the name. No quotation marks are needed.